# Cola de prioridad Java no deja poner más de un elemento

Tags: java

Como puedo hacer para que me deje poner más de un elemento en mi cola de prioridad
Tengo una clase alumno con los atributos apellido nombre codigo y promedio donde si tiene mayor promedio se retira la cosa es que cuando pongo dos elementos me manda error

```
   String apellido="fulano";
    String Nombre="perez";
    String codigo="14532";  
    int promedio=5;
    
    String apellido2="luis";
    String Nombre2="contreras";
    String codigo2="14572";  
    int promedio2=5;
    
    
    Alumno alu1= new Alumno(apellido,Nombre,codigo,promedio);
    Alumno alu2 = new Alumno(apellido2,Nombre2,codigo2,promedio2);

    CPMax<Alumno> cp = new CPMax<Alumno>();
    
    cp.insertar(alu1);
    cp.mostrarCp();
    cp.insertar(alu2);
```

La clase CPMax, esta clase la paso un profesor y nos dijo que lo usaramos

```````````
   public CPMax(Clave[] claves) {
        N = claves.length;
        cp = (Clave[]) new Object[claves.length + 1]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            cp[i+1] = claves[i];
        for (int k = N/2; k >= 1; k--)
            hundir(k);
        assert esMonticuloMax();
    }

``````````

Ese es el método para insertar


   public void insertar(Clave x) {
        if (N >= cp.length - 1) redimensionar(2 * cp.length);

        cp[++N] = x;
        emerger(N);
        assert esMonticuloMax();
    }
```````````

Comment: ¿Esto ocasiona algún error en tiempo de compilación o de ejecución? ¿Cuál es ese error?. Dado que la clase `CPMax` no es estándar de java y sospecho que el problema tiene que ver con ella, ¿Puedes poner una referencia a su documentación? Un saludo.

Comment: Ah, olvidé darte la bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito también a leer [ask]. Un saludo.

Comment: Pues el error se da en tiempo de ejecución, si ahora lo pongo